# Caliburn micro telerik radmaskedtextbox convention

Tags: telerik, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to define a caliburm micro convention for telerik RadMaskedTextBox control 
And tried this based on this URL: https://github.com/vcaraulean/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik/blob/master/Caliburn.Micro.Telerik/TelerikConventions.cs

ConventionManager.AddElementConvention(RadMaskedTextBox.MaskedTextProperty, "MaskedText", "ValueChanged");

This didn't worked though it is similar to basic text box convention.
Any direction is appreciated
Thanks- Rajesh cheedalla